# where to place firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to call `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged` in my react component. Firebase is working and the `console.log("hi")` is triggered. However, it triggers permanently rather than just on logging in. As a result, I can see a never ending stream of console logs. How can I edit the below to achieve the desired result?

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/auth';
import 'firebase/compat/database';
import 'firebase/compat/storage';

import './App.css';
import React, { Component } from 'react';

const firebaseConfig = {
  ...
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)


const auth = firebase.auth()
const database = firebase.database()
var database_ref = database.ref()
var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();


class App extends Component {
  state={}
  

  render(){

   firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((curUser) => {
    if(curUser!=null){
      console.log("hi")
    })
    }})

  return (<React.Fragment></React.Fragment>);
  };
}

export default App;
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In class components, the spot for this is typically componentDidMount, and tear down the subscription in componentWillUnmount:

```
class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.unsubscribe = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((curUser) => {
      if(curUser!=null){
        console.log("hi")
      }
   }})
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.unsubscribe();
  }

  // ...
}
```

You may want to set state when the user changes, so the component can rerender and other parts of the code can use the new user.